# XSL - Get SUM of price

Tags: php, xml, xslt, sum

I have a xml structure like:

```
<PartsDetail> <Id>1481</Id> <Desc>test1</Desc> <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc> <Price Cur="UAH">+798.27</Price> </PartsDetail> 
<PartsDetail> <Id>0741</Id> <Desc>test2</Desc> <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc> <Price Cur="UAH">+399.14</Price> </PartsDetail>
```

And in view, I make some transformation with "price" (I bring to view like 399.14).

I use this for transformation:

```
<xsl:call-template name="showNumberWithThousands">
 <xsl:with-param name="value">
 <xsl:call-template name="parseNumber">
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="Price"/>
</xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

Also I need to take a sum of price now.
I tried to use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//Data/Paint//PartsDetail/@Price)"/>
```

But the a result is - NaN.

As I understand I need to transform the price in "normal view (without + and -)" before a send it to function "sum".

To: @michael.hor257k

Structure is more complicated.
I use your solution - but it didn't work. It looks like I'm doing something wrong

```
<xsl:template name="PaintSum"> 
<xsl:variable name="corrected-prices"> 
<xsl:for-each select="//CalcData/Paint/PaintDtl"> 
<price> <xsl:value-of select="translate(MatAmnt, '+', '')"/> </price> 
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:variable> 
<sum> <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($corrected-prices)/price)"/> </sum>
</xsl:template>
```

And when I  use  `<xsl:call-template name="PaintSum"/>`
Nothing happens. Similarly, further request into templates stop working.

I'm trying to use:

```
<xsl:variable name="corrected-prices">
        <xsl:for-each select="//CalcData/Paint//PaintDtl">
            <price>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(MatAmnt, '+', '')"/>
            </price>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

And add sum in text by :

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($corrected-prices)/price)"/>
```

But output file - crashes.

$corrected-prices contains "1086.65286.75".

**How can I turn this into a sum?**

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful

Comment: "*Structure is more complicated. I use your solution - but it didn't work.*" **1.** I don't see your structure, so I cannot help you with that. -- **2.** You are **not** using my solution.

Comment: Structure has additional information (But it does not matter).
I tried add your templates to my file and call it. (To put this information in right place).

I change name of attribute to correct (MatAmnt etc.) - in first example I use assumed names

Comment: I give additional information about problem

Comment: Good question, +1. I just provided a solution that doesn't depend on any extension functions and doesn't create any intermediary result tree (which consumes memory). In fact, this transformation runs in constant memory if the XSLT processor recognizes tail recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand I need transform price to "normal view (without + and
>   -)" before a send it to function "sum".

That is more or less correct (you don't want to remove the minus sign, in case the number is negative). Given a well-formed input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <PartsDetail>
    <Id>1481</Id>
    <Desc>test1</Desc>
    <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc>
    <Price Cur="UAH">+798.27</Price>
  </PartsDetail>
  <PartsDetail>
    <Id>0741</Id>
    <Desc>test2</Desc>
    <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc>
    <Price Cur="UAH">+399.14</Price>
  </PartsDetail>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="corrected-prices">
        <xsl:for-each select="PartsDetail">
            <price>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(Price, '+', '')"/>
            </price>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <sum>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($corrected-prices)/price)"/>
    </sum>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sum>1197.41</sum>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation doesn't require the use of any extension functions and doesn't produce an intermediary tree** -- in fact it runs with 0 additional memory and is suitable for streaming, if the XSLT processor recognizes tail-recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="(*/Price/text())[1]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="*/Price/text()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="sum">
  <xsl:param name="pTotal" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNodes"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNode1" select="translate($pNodes[1],'+','')"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="substring($pTotal+$pNode1, 1 div not($pNodes[2]))"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pNodes[2][$pNode1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pTotal" select="$pTotal+$pNode1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pNodes" select="$pNodes[position()>1]"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When it is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
  <PartsDetail>
    <Id>1481</Id>
    <Desc>test1</Desc>
    <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc>
    <Price Cur="UAH">+798.27</Price>
  </PartsDetail>
  <PartsDetail>
    <Id>0741</Id>
    <Desc>test2</Desc>
    <GlobDesc>test2</GlobDesc>
    <Price Cur="UAH">+399.14</Price>
  </PartsDetail>
</root>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1187.4099999999998
```